Ubuntu and fqdn
I am writing to the community because I need some clarifications regarding ubuntu and fqdn. Topic is similar to this one: Ubuntu server installation sets invalid FQDN
With ubuntu servers version 22.04 and 24.04 the hostname --fqdn command fails in providing the machine fqdn. The getfqdn() method of the python socket library also fails in capturing it
I know that exchanging the lookup order on the hosts line of the nsswitch.conf, putting dns first, would fix the issue, however I wonder if it is good way to fix it.
Also, I noticed similar configurations in centos like distribs, but with a proper capturing of fqdn both with hostname --fqdn and the python lib.
My questions are, shouldn't the hostname --fqdn always capture the fqdn when available, no matter the lookup order in the nsswitch.conf? If it should and doesn't capture it, is it a failure in that command and further in the python lib too or something related to ubuntu distrib? Finally is it now expected for users to manually exchange the lookup order in the nsswitch.conf file?
It's important for us cause we work on an application that should install on both ubuntu and centos like servers of our customers, that application is probing the fqdn and now fails on ubuntu. So we need to know if configuring the nsswitch.conf of ubuntu is now part of the prerequisites of installing our app.
Hope I have been clear enough. Regards.

I finally found a convenient solution to my problem. I started using the getent command with option: getent hosts $hostname -s dns. Works like a charm

I believe you will find it also gets you the first FQDN.
Try hostname --all-fqdns instead.
I suspect you will find that your basic hostname is listed as the name for 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts.  This would reasonably be the first found.  (my system actually finds "localhost".)

That's true, I forgot to write it but the hostname -A do the job and capture the fqdn. However I think the python socket.getfqdn() does the same job than hostname -f. That's why I wanted to show the parrallel

OK.  It appears to be reading /etc/hosts for 127.0.0.1.  The python version is taking the first name, not a later one.  If you want data from the net, try getting a network address for the machine and using socket.gethostbyaddr()
